# Multi-module spring-boot jpa application

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot

I'm in trouble refactoring a monolithic application into a multi-module structure:

```
-\
 + core (jpa domain entities, services, ...)
 + command-line-utils
 + web-app
```

I've moved classes and configured the pom files so that everything compiles and the web app executes correctly.

I cannot understand how to move into the core module the basic junit tests I originally had: I cannot stop having errors concerning missing @Autowired repositories.

I understand that I probably should define some sort of **configuration class** (?) in the core module (I do not have any special configuration concerning persistence in the original moloc except datasource parameters in properties file).

Comment: You can do it by configure all the beans on a configuration class with the configuration annotation and then declare each bean with bean or add the service on each class you are trying to autowire (assuming your configuration is scanning all classes you try to autowire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved (this issue) defining a `@SpringbootApplication` annotated class in `src/test/java` referenced with `@SpringApplicationConfiguration(class = MyTestApp.class )` in test classes.

In this way the usual spring-boot magic `:-)` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can define configuration right inside your JUnit tests. Use `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` and `@ContextConfiguration` annotation from `org.springframework.test.context` package.

Inside your test you can define configuration as needed with Mocks and real classes in static class, e.g.

```
    @Configuration
    public static class Config {

        @Bean
        public RestOperations restTemplate() {
            return mock(RestOperations.class);
        }

        ....
    }
```